# Chrome extension that modifies response headers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a extension that will modify some response headers. I did the extension and I think it modifies the header value, but the problem is that the modified header value does not appear in inspect element window (Network tab).

The headers I am suppose to change are Set-Cookie headers and after my code changes the value I can see the new value with a cookie viewer extension (EditThisCookie), but the behavior of the content stays as if the cookie was not modified (content modifies based on cookie value).

I will attach the code below of the script and manifest file.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "Getting started example",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/logo.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.domain.com/"
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
var callback = function(details) {
  if (details.type == "main_frame") {
    process_headers(details);
    console.log("Finished processing headers for request with url: ", details.url);
  }
  var final_response_headers = details.responseHeaders;
  console.log(final_response_headers);
  return {responseHeaders: final_response_headers};
};

function process_headers(details) {
  var responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders;
  for (var i in responseHeaders) {
    var responseHeader = responseHeaders[i];
    if (responseHeader.name == "Set-Cookie") {
      try_changing_value(responseHeader);
    }
  }
}

function try_changing_value(header) {
  var value = header.value;
  var expected_value = "sub_cookie1";
  var viewed_count_index = value.indexOf(expected_value);
  if (viewed_count_index != -1) {
    var two_points_index = value.indexOf(":", viewed_count_index);
    var comma_index = value.indexOf(",", viewed_count_index);
    var result = value.substring(0, two_points_index + 1) + "5" + value.substring(comma_index);
    header.value = result;
  }
}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(callback, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

The original Set-Cookie header value looks like this:

```
cookie=sub_cookie:5,sub_sub_cookie:0;Version=1;Comment=;Domain=.domain.com;Path=/;Max-Age=3600
```

To sum it up, why doesn't the new value appear on the inspect element Network tab when checking the response headers? Is it no changed correctly?

Many thanks

Comment: Simple answer: don't do this, [set cookies directly](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) instead.

Comment: I don't see a probelm with your code. `sub_cookie1` is not found and your code does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant sub_cookie.
I did manage to use the code, it was correct, just cleared the cookies before running the plugin.